# Encoding with Android MediaCodec

Tags: android, hardware, media, encode, codec

i'd like to know if anybody can provide me any link or useful info about encoding video with Android MediaCodec Library.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions to understand why your question is not specific enough for SO.

Comment: http://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec

Comment: https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo

Answer (score 2):

The [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) page in the Android documentation is where you should start. There is also a video from the [authoritative Google I/O 2012 session](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/117/) that's [available on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmCqJlzIUXs).

These links are all from a quick Google search. Please also see the comment from @mah above.